# Exampleprovided not working

Tags: google-schemas

I have tried the gmail action example provided [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial)

But no button is coming up in inbox. I am following instructions and doing testing for my gmail account.

Any help will be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickstart sample is perfectly working. I've attached a screenshot as proof:

[image]

Check the steps indicated in [Creating the project](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial#creating_the_project) once again and be sure you have both the Code.gs and html file named `mail_template`. Also, make sure that the function `testSchemas` is selected in the Select function dropdown menu.

Comment: Thanks, yes its working, my html template for some reason was not saved